# body height 100% bigger than screen height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've set my `html body` tag heigth to be `100%` but in Firefox that shows as a few more pixels than the screen has, so a nav scroll bar appears. How can I adjust that other than specifiying an arbitrary `height :98%`? I've set `padding` and `margin` to zero.

I'm using only bootstrap for css, if that's of any importance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check elements inside the `body`. One of it probably has margins or even content that goes outside the `body` element. Just try to delete all inner elements one by one in Firefox's dev.tools and notice which element deletion will solve the problem.

Comment: Nevermind, the problem is that an inner div has height = 100%, but it has another element above it so their heights combined expand the body.

Comment: If you are searching for an issue like this and you don't understand where this top margin is coming from definitely follow this answer. I've been searching for hours on end only to find one of the h3 child elements had the standard browser h3 top-margin applied and was pushing the page height.

Answer (score 2):

Just to follow up the answer above, I noticed that padding can cause the same effect, but can only be noticed when inspecting the elements.

```html
<button class="sbtn">
    <span class="text">
        my btn
    </span>
</button>

.sbtn {
    height: 5vh;
    background-color: red;
}

.text {
    padding: 10vh;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your main CSS file.

```
/* CSS */

* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

border-box tells the browser to account for any border and padding in the values you specify for an element's width and height. If you set an element's width to 100 pixels, that 100 pixels will include any border or padding you added, and the content box will shrink to absorb that extra width. This typically makes it much easier to size elements.

[CSS box sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)